# How to manipulate solution outputs that appear in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list `{E, {p, ϕ}}`, and I need values `E`, `p`, and `ϕ` such that I can later on do operations with them (like `ArcCos[p]`, etc.). I will be repeatedly generating the values in the list, as a list, so doing this by-hand is not an option. How do I get them out of the list?

In this case, the values `E`, `p`, and `ϕ` exist such that they appear as `p -> 0.097`, `ϕ -> 0.03`, etc. I need them such that calling, for example, for `list = {E, {p, ϕ}}`, `list[[2,1]]` yields `0.097` and not `p -> 0.097`. This is the issue.

Comment: E is euler's number - don't use capital letters. If you have `result = {e,{p,ϕ}}` then `e = First[result]` and `{p,ϕ} = {p,ϕ}/.Last[result]`

Comment: Following what @flinty says, what you get is called a list of "rules", which means that you can replace a symbol with its value using these rules, like `p /. {p -> 0.097}` gives `0.097`.

Comment: I didn't actually use E, I simply shortened a variable for posting on this website, sorry that that wasn't obviously clear. Got it, I will implement. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you not just avoid making them into rules initially?

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit

To answer your question I will use the following test data because the my answer doesn't have any dependency of the variable names or the data values that appear in your code. It only depends of the *structure* of the data.

```
data = {#1, {#2, #3}} & @@ MapThread[Rule, {{a, b, c}, Range[3]}]
```

> `{a -> 1, {b -> 2, c -> 3}}`

All you need to do is map `Part` over the data at level specification `{-2}`, which is the level of the rules in the data. Like so:

```
val = Map[#[[2]]&, data, {-2}]
```

> `{1, {2, 3}}`

However, I recommend the following  as a better way to proceed.

```
val = Flatten[data][[All, 2]]
```

> `{1, 2, 3}`

Then your further references to the values will be simpler.